# Почему происходит ошибка ClassNotFound: org.postgresql.Driver в веб-приложении, хотя в обычном все работает?

Tags: java, postgresql, java-ee, maven

У меня есть maven веб приложение с томкатом. Я хочу использовать в своем приложении базу данных. В зависимостях указываю все правильно, но почему то происходит ошибка
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver` в `Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");`. Кусок из зависимостей:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Я создал новое обычное приложение(без томката и сервелетов), в зависимостях указал тоже самое. Переписал туда кусок для работы с бд. И приложение работает правильно. Почему и что делать? Запускаю все из IntelliJ.

pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<properties>
    <maven.compile.source>1.8</maven.compile.source>
    <maven.compile.target>1.8</maven.compile.target>
</properties>
```

Собираю так: компилирую в IntelliJ, потом из `out` переношу в папку в `webapps`. Или запускаю сразу из IntelliJ.

Comment: как вы на томкат деплоете? jar собираете со всеми зависимостями или же легковестный?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor с зависимостями

Comment: покажите ваш pom и как вы собираете

Comment: забыл плюсануть +)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Драйвер `postgresql` нужно класть в `lib` томката  к сожалению или к счастью - это уж Вам решать, мне всегда это только лишь мешало. Не знаю как сейчас с этим дела обстоят, я больше чем 5 томкат в дикой природе не встерчал, Раньше так было.

PS: Это [гуглится](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/tomcat.html)

Comment: Да, спасибо, это сработало

Comment: @AntonSorokin а какой Вас томкатец?

Comment: у меня 9, последний

Comment: @AntonSorokin значит не поменялось ничего в датском королевстве

Comment: @AntonSorokin a что должно было поменяться-то ? Нужно правильно делать - в поме прописать packaging war, добавить war плагин, особенно, если проект нестандартно создан и все прописать, что откуда брать, прописать скопы правильно (для того же драйвера посгре), и собрать проект не средой через билд, а maven'ом, тогда будет нормальный war'ник, который деплоится на томкет (если по http, то можно прямо maven'ом и деплоить, используя соответствующий плагин). Вообще, все это элементарно делается.

Comment: @keekkenen спасибо, так и сделаю